# Задача по js на понимание привязки контекста

Tags: javascript

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу и объясните решение.

Требуется написать функцию - `bindFunc`:

```
var add = function(a,b) { return a+b;}
var add2 = bindFunc(add, 2);
add2(6)  // outputs 8
add2(10) // outputs 12
```

Понимаю, что тут надо как-то передать контекст и написать своеобразный полифил bind, но дойти до решения не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так, данный прием называется **Карринг (Carrying)**:

```js
function bindFunc(func, a){
   return func.bind(null, a);
}

var add = function(a,b) { return a+b;}
var add2 = bindFunc(add, 2);
console.log(add2(6));  // outputs 8
console.log(add2(10)); // outputs 12
```

В данном случае контекст не используется.

[Источник](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind#%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае к контексту задача не имеет отношение. 
Тут применяется ***каррирование***.

Разберем на примере:

У наc есть функция `add`, как в вашем вопросе. Функция довольно простая:

```
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
```

Но допустим, у нас появилась нужда иметь функцию, которая складывает число с 10ю.
Да, мы можем писать вот так

```
add(5, 10);
add(11, 10);
add(15, 10);
```

Но тут велик шанс опечататься, да и если потом 10 нужно будет поменять на 11, то это вызовет много проблем. Можно завести переменную для этого "магического числа", но есть и другой способ ( функциональный ).

Что если бы у нас была уже функция, которая принимает одно число и складывает с 10. Назовем ее `addTo10(num)`, сам ее код тоже очень простой

```
const addTo10 = (a) => a + 10;
```

Выглядит неплохо, но у нас ведь уже есть `add`, почему бы не использовать ее?

`bindFunc` как раз поможет нам в этом. Первым параметром мы передаем функцию, которая будет вызываться, а потом передаем список предустановленных параметров. В итоге `bindFunc` вернет нам функцию-обертку, которая вызовет начальную функцию с параметрами, которые получила сама + предустановленные параметры

```
// вариант через замыкание
const bindFunc = (fn, ...params) => {
    return (...otherParams) => fn(...params, ...otherParams);
}

// вариант через apply
const bindFuncWithApply = (fn, ...params) => {
    return fn.bind(null, ...params)
}

// используем
const add = (a, b) => a + b;
const addTo2 = bindFunc(add, 2);
const addTo10 = bindFuncWithApply(add, 10);

console.log(addTo2(2));
console.log(addTo10(10));
```

Можно экспериментировать дальше

```
const sum = (...params) => params.reduce(add, 0);

const sumWith10 = bindFunc(sum, 10);
const sumWith10And100 = bindFunc(sum, 10, 100);

console.log(sum(3, 2, 5));
console.log(sumWith10(10, 10));
console.log(sumWith10And100(50, 40));
```

Answer (score 0):

вообще не поняла, зачем столько сложности и теории, все же просто:

```
const add = (a, b) => a+b

const bindFunc = (add, num) => {
  return (a) => (add(a, num))
}

const add2 = bindFunc(add, 2);
```

---

```
add2(6)  // outputs 8
add2(10) // outputs 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно именно через bind, то я вижу следующую реализацию:

```js
var add = function(a,b) { return a+b;}

var bindFunc = (func, param ) => { return func.bind(null, param)}

var add2 = bindFunc(add, 2);

add2(6); //8

add2(10); //12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add(a, b) {return a + b;}
let bindFunc = add.bind(add, 2);
console.log( bindFunc(6) );
console.log( bindFunc(10) );
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

```
function bindFunc(context, params) {
  return function(args) {
    console.log(context.bind(context, params)(args));
  }
} 

var add = function(a,b) { return a+b;}
var add2 = bindFunc(add, 2);
add2(6)  // outputs 8
add2(10) // outputs 12
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]